# fixed scroll button issue

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed scroll to top button on my website I am trying to develop - http://harden6615.com/portfolio/index.html. I have the wrapper div position relative and the scroll div #hb-gotop fixed, but the button adjusts to the browser instead of the wrapper. Any suggestions?

Also a side problem is my header background in IE has a problem. If anyone sees what's causing that would be great, but not the issue in this thread. Thanks.

Comment: Ryan, that's not helpful at all. Everyone has to learn things at some point. Simple, yes, but try using your energy to help and educate someone rather than put them down.

Answer (score 0):

You want it to be positioned within your container?

Change your button CSS to this:

```
#hb-gotop{
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #434343;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    right:10px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color: #45FFE0;
    text-decoration:none;
    }
```

Fixed locks it to the window screen, so you need absolute instead.

Please let me know if I'm confusing what you're asking here.

Thanks,
Michael.

Comment: Well I wanted it to be fixed vertically similar to the vertical sidebars instead of horizontal, but I guess thats a bit more jquery work. Thanks.